# authentification in a java application

Tags: java, mysql

it's my first time in development field and i'm really stuck -_-
 I'm developing a java application using netbeans IDE 7.4. I created all my frames and they are all working. I have a table in my database  named (user) contains one username and password(i'm using mysql with wampserver) the activation of all the interfaces comes after the identification . now i want to add another user with limited privileges(can't use some buttons) how is it possible to do that? Do i have to create two versions of every frame for each user? and how to connect them to the database?

Comment: Sounds like you need another table to assign users to specific roles that have permission to use certain parts of the application.  How you do this is way too broad a question for this site.

Comment: User-Group-Role is the usual idiom: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control.  Spring Security is a well-designed module.  I'd prefer using that to inventing my own: http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would handle this with a function being called right after logging in (identification). Essentially an authorize privileges function that will enable/disable buttons accordingly.

Example,

```
private void authPrivs(userLevel)
{
switch(userLevel)
     case "Admin":
           break;
     case "Limited":
           buttonAdmin.setEnabled(false);
           buttonAdmin2.setEnabled(false);
           break;
}
```

Because you have already designed the GUI with admin privileges defaulted, enabling is not necessary in the switch statement. You could even make the buttons disappear with setVisible(), but that might make your GUI really ugly.

Edit: Just to clarify, I would suggest making a field in your database that stores the "userLevel" variable. Once your user logs in, pull that userLevel off his login, and pass it to authPrivs().

Comment: if you can please detail how can i store the useLevel variable and where, and how to set such variable.

Comment: So in your database, your fields should look similar to something like UserID, Username, Password, and userLevel. For clarity, make userLevel a text field. Just as your doing with your identification process, pull the userLevel as well and store it in a string variable in your application. If the user successfully logs in, then from within that function you can call authPrivs(userLevel).